# GLUT windows does not refresh

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have been developing a game engine from scratch, using c++, openGL and GLUT for some time. I was using my computer and the engine was ok but recently I have bought a laptop so I decided to try my engine on it. When I started the engine it was working with frame rate like 0.3 fps but after the installation of new drivers for the GPU everything went ok. Unfortunately a new problem has arisen, in my opinion, out of nowhere. When I start the application the screen refreshes only if I am continuously clicking any mouse button even if I don't have a glutMouseFunc() or if I alt+tab the window. I don't have any idea what could be the reason so if you have any ideas I am open to them.

Comment: I haven't work with GLUT for a while, but from described it looks like your app refreshes the screen not on each frame but only in case of events like mouse movement and window being redrawn. Could you post the display function, or the part of code containing `glClear(); ... glutSwapBuffers();` ?

Comment: I really don't think the problem is in the code because the exact same code works perfectly at my computer. However, here is my display function:
`void displayGL()
{
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 ...
 glutSwapBuffers();
}`
I also have `glutPostRedisplay()` in an idle and a passive motion function so this is not the problem too.

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting:

```
glutPostRedisplay();
```

after your key and mouse functions.
Ex.

```
static void key(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case 27 :
        case 'q':
           exit(0);
        break;

    }

    glutPostRedisplay();//this is what I mean
}
```

That is what works for me.

Comment: I have the `glutPostRedisplay()` function at several glut functions and also I have tried putting it in every glut function but it didn't work. I think the problem is not in the code but elsewhere but really don't have any idea what could be the reason of this.